# Background-color not working

Tags: php, html, css

Hi Im trying to display the current time in this format in php.. but with background blue and text white..

```
Current Time: Fri Sep 21 11:06:46 2007
```

My problem is that in my CSS file I have the following syntax for the background...

```
body{
/* fallback */
background-color: #C0C0C0;
/*background: url(images/linear_bg_2.png);*/
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

but in my php file when the user inputs the right format of time display, my time should display with the background blue and text white.. the text is actually working fine but the background is not making the change..

This what I have for my php file..

```
<?php
}// End of IF statement
    if($_POST && $_POST['userInput'] == "comp" && $_POST['userInput'] != ""){
        ?><body style="background-color:#0000CC;color:white;"><?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
        echo "Current Time: " . date("D M d H:i:s Y");
        ?></body><?php
    }
```

Well, I hope someone know or can see what I am doing wrong.. I will really appreciate it..

Comment: ... background-color:#0000CC ....

Comment: Besides the fact that you forgot the `#`, another way of doing this would be `if(isset... rest of conditions) { include 'css_1.css'; } else { include 'css_2.css'; }` that way you can change things globally if you have a lot of files.

Comment: Does it validate (check both the HTML and CSS)?

Comment: I would try this instead. Replace `?><body style="background-color:#0000CC;color:white;"><?php` with `echo '<body style="background-color:#0000CC;color:white;">';` and add an `else` condition with a different style. That worked for me in testing  without your full code/form.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the `#` before the hex color.

```
?><body style="background-color:#0000CC;color:white;"><?php
```

Comment: Sorry my bad.. but my problem still been the same.. Maybe I did a mistake typing in my problem..

Comment: Your body markup is fine. Check to make sure your if statement is actually being evaluated properly. Best guess is that one or more of your 3 conditions is false, so the body tag isn't being written out with the blue background. But you haven't provided enough code for us to check.

Comment: @JV17 Check to see if you don't already have a/another CSS stylesheet possibly overriding your style or in your HTML itself. Plus this is probably at fault `if($_POST && $_POST['userInput']`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I only have one CCS stylesheet that contains the code that is first as body{...} I wanted to do an inline or something that will override the properties from that stylesheet..

Comment: @JV17 The problem may also be that, you're going in and out of PHP and the element you're trying to style is not in PHP itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fix the problem in this way...

instep of using

```
?><body style="background-color:#0000CC;color:white;"><?php
```

I changed to...

```
?><body style="background:#0000CC;color:white;"><?php
```

and it made it happen.. overrides the css stylesheet... Thanks guys..

Comment: Well that is bizarre. Oh well, as long as you found "your" solution is all that counts. ;-)

Comment: @jv17, just accept the other answer then.